# Uniform upper bound for the sum over primes $\sum_{p \leq x} p^{-1+\varepsilon}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

I am reading the article *D. M. Gordon and C. Pomerance, The distribution of Lucas and elliptic pseudoprime, Math. Comp. (1991)* ([click](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper82.pdf)).
In equation (27) the authors, apparently, used the following upper bound for a sum over the prime numbers:
$$(\star)\quad\sum_{p \leq x} p^{-1+\varepsilon} \ll \frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon\log x} ,$$
for sufficiently large $x > 0$ and sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, where the implicit constant in $\ll$ is absolute. (Precisely, $\varepsilon = \frac{4+\log\log\log x}{\log\log x}$, but I hope that this is not really important.) 
I am trying to prove ($\star$) but since now I have failed. Clearly, one way can be using partial summation and the prime number theorem, for example
$$\sum_{p \leq x} p^{-1+\varepsilon} = \pi(x) x^{-1+\varepsilon} + (1-\varepsilon)\int_2^x \pi(t)t^{-2+\varepsilon}dt ,$$
but then I am now been able to prove the claim. I also throught that
$$\sum_{p \leq x} p^{-1+\varepsilon} \leq \sum_{n \leq \pi(x)} n^{-1+\varepsilon} \ll \int_0^{\pi(x)} t^{-1+\varepsilon}dt = \frac{\pi(x)^\varepsilon}{\varepsilon} \ll \frac{x^\varepsilon}{\varepsilon (\log x)^\varepsilon} ,$$
but his is too weak.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Could you be more precise whether your "sufficiently large" $x$ and "sufficiently small" $\epsilon$ depend on each other? And how?

Comment: @FanZheng There exists $x_0 > 0$ and $\varepsilon_0 > 0$ such that for any $x > x_0$ and $\varepsilon < \varepsilon_0$ the claim holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The left hand side of $(\star)$ is at least
$$ \sum_{p\leq x}p^{-1}=\log\log x +O(1), $$
hence a necessary condition for the truth of $(\star)$ is that
$$ \frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon\log x} \gg \log\log x.$$
This condition is also sufficient, in the light of the following bound that I prove below:
$$ (\star\star)\quad\sum_{p \leq x} (p^{-1+\varepsilon} - p^{-1})\ll \frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon\log x}. $$
In particular, $(\star)$ is valid for $\varepsilon>(\log\log\log x + \log\log\log\log x)/ \log x$, since in this case
$$ \frac{x^{\varepsilon}}{\varepsilon\log x} >  \frac{(\log\log x)(\log\log\log x)}{\log\log\log x + \log\log\log\log x} \gg \log\log x.$$

Now let me prove $(\star\star)$:
$$ \sum_{p \leq x} (p^{-1+\varepsilon} - p^{-1}) \ll \sum_{p\leq e^{1/\varepsilon}}\frac{\varepsilon\log p}{p}+\int_{e^{1/\varepsilon}}^x t^{-1+\varepsilon}\,d\pi(t) $$
$$ \ll 1+\frac{x^\varepsilon}{\log x}+\int_{e^{1/\varepsilon}}^x \frac{t^{-1+\varepsilon}}{\log t}\,dt
= 1+\frac{x^\varepsilon}{\log x}+\int_1^{\varepsilon\log x}\frac{e^t}{t}dt\,\ll\frac{e^{\varepsilon\log x}}{\varepsilon\log x}=\frac{x^\varepsilon}{\varepsilon\log x}. $$

Comment: Are you drowning?:)

Comment: Thank you very much for you proof, it was exactly what I was looking about.

Answer (score 2):

The main (and only) theorem in the said paper by T. Salát and S. Znám is the following one:

*For any* $a>0,$ *let us denote the sum* $\sum_{p \leq x} p^{a}$ *with* $S_{a}(x)$. *Then, we have that*

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{S_{a}(x) \cdot\log x}{x^{1+a}} = \frac{1}{1+a}.$$

Their proof depends on the Prime Number Theorem. In case you want to take a look at the paper, you can find it here: http://goo.gl/kUO6Zt

Last but not least, note that the late P. S. Bruckman may have had a different proof of this result:

https://www.siam.org/journals/categories/08-005.php

Comment: No one reads any more :(

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to [Salat and Znam](https://www.dropbox.com/s/evwlz0vvsekgcry/salatznam.pdf?dl=0), 1968. The link is to a review, I have no idea how to find the actual paper.The result of Prachar cited in the review may be easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct consequence of the prime number theorem (or weaker estimates on $\pi(x)$):
$$
\sum_{p\le x} p^{-1+\epsilon} = \int_1^x t^{-1+\epsilon}\, d\pi(t) =\pi(x)x^{-1+\epsilon}+(1-\epsilon)\int_1^x t^{-2+\epsilon}\pi(t)\, dt ,
$$
by an integration by parts. Now use that $\pi(x)\lesssim x/\log x$. The first term is already of the desired order. Split the integral into two parts, according to $t\le x^{\epsilon}/\log x$ and $t$ larger than this bound. Again, the first part is clearly $\lesssim x^{\epsilon}/\log x$. On the second interval, we have that $\log t\gtrsim \epsilon \log x$, which produces the desired bound after integrating.

Comment: But is the estimate uniform in $\epsilon$, e.g., in the second part $\log t\ge \epsilon\log x-\log\log x$. Why is it $\gg \epsilon\log x$ with a uniform constant?

Comment: @FanZheng: It sure is; $\log\log x\le (\epsilon/2)\log x$, say.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but that's true only in some sense of the two "sufficiently" above. In other words, does the "sufficient largeness" of $x$ depend on $\epsilon$?

Comment: @FanZheng: Yes, I guess that's what I show: $\limsup S_{\epsilon}(x)x^{-\epsilon}\log x\le C/\epsilon$, and this $C$ doesn't depend on anything.

Comment: Definitely I'm in great shape with the OP's extra specification which makes $\log\log x/\epsilon$ small.